# Resampling and plotting dataframe in pythong

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to resample and plot the AverageTemperature column of a dataframe based on the values of 2 other columns (Country and City) but I keep getting an error that I can't seem to resolve.

[image: Code and Error]

Note: dt are dateTime objects

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the column names are `Country` and `City`, you will want to update your code to:

```
df2 = df[(df["City"] == "Aden") & (df["Country"] == "Yemen")]["AverageTemperature"].copy()
```

Comment: It won't let me give you an upvote because I'm new to the platform. But this worked, thank you for the help. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
df2 = df.query("(Country == 'Yemen') & (City == 'Aden')")["AverageTemperature"].copy(deep=True)
```

If you don't put deep = True, you will have a shallow copy, any changes made on the original will reflect on the copy/copies.

Comment: This was also a viable solution, thank you for responding :)